# Image not visible in a NextJS component

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js

In a Firebase web app, I have the following NextJS component:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from 'next/image'
import "./displayShop.css";
import telImg from '../images/Telephone.png';


export default function DisplayShop(
  {name,phone,address,web_site,food_type}:
  {name:string,phone:string,address?:string,
    web_site?:string,food_type?:string}) {
    
  return (
    <div className='Card'>
      <div className='RNT'>
        <div className='RN'>{name}</div>
        <div className='RT'>{phone}</div>
        <a href={`tel:${phone}`} className='telIcn'>
          <Image
            className='img'
            src={telImg}
            alt="Telephone-Clip"
            width={70}
            height={70} />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className='RTS'>
        {address &&
          <div className='RA'>{address}</div>
        }
      </div>
      {food_type &&
        <div className='RF'>{food_type}</div>
      }
      {web_site &&
      <div>
        <Link className='RW' href={web_site}
              target='_blank'>{web_site}</Link>
      </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
} /* End of ShowData */
```

Here is the problem I have. When used I only see the alt part of the  Image component (Telephone-Clip). I do not see the image itself. Why is that ?

And how can this issue be soved?

To provide some more information; I see this in the Web Developer Tools console of the browser:

```
GET
https://myapp.web.app/_next/image?url=/_next/static/media/Telephone.04133dbb.png&w=96&q=75
[HTTP/3 404  123ms]

GET
    https://myapp.web.app/_next/image?url=/_next/static/media/Telephone.04133dbb.png&w=96&q=75
Status
404
VersionHTTP/3
Transferred2.61 kB (6.68 kB size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request PriorityLowest
DNS ResolutionSystem
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get an HTTP 404 in your browser for the image. It looks like, from the path in the import that the image is not in the public folder, which results in the image not being available to the browser/web.

If you move the image to the public folder (and not an image subfolder in it, you need to update your Image src with something like:

```
<Image className="img" src="/Telephone.png" alt="Telephone-Clip" width={70} height={70}/>
```

src path starts from the public folder (assuming you set a `/` to begin with)
And you don't need the import

Comment: Actually I see a 404 error in the web console indeed. Concerning the public folder, since I use "firebase experiments:enable webframeworks" I am not sure where the public folder is.

Comment: Copying the image in the public folder at the top has no effect.

Comment: After some investigation I found that the image is copied to .next/static/media/Telephone.04133dbb.png. But as I wrote it does not show up.

Comment: From the root folder in your project, you should have a public folder created (when you created the app), if not, create it. Then, you need to update your `<Image src` accordingly. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried it. That does not work. The public folder exists but only contains next.svg vercel.svg.